# VBA error in copying the workbooks to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying the combine the all workbooks from a folder  after some changes into on one new workbook, each workbook has only one sheet. But my code is not woking at following line:

`wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)`

Could you please check what is causing the error?

```
Sub CombineIDBISheet()
    
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook As Workbook
    
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook
                If Range("B4") = "Search Criteria" Then
                    Cells.WrapText = False
                    Cells.UnMerge
                    Dim x
                    With Range("d7", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                    x = .Address
                    .Value = Evaluate("index(date(mid(" & x & ",7,4),mid(" & x & ",4,2),left(" & x & ",2))+timevalue(right(" & x & ",8)),,)")
                    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                        With .Offset(, 1)
                        .TextToColumns .Cells(1), 1, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)
                        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                        End With
                    End With
        
                    With Range("j7:k" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
                    .Value = .Value
                    .UnMerge
                    End With
                Range("b3:b5").Copy Range("c3:c5")
                Columns("a:b").EntireColumn.Delete
                Columns("i").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                Columns("L:p").EntireColumn.Delete
                Else
                End If
     
            Range("B4").ClearContents
            wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You never declare `wksCurSheet `.  I think you need `Set wksCurSheet = ActiveSheet 'or whatever`, somewhere (I think after your `With Workbooks.Open()` line? Also you do have tons of un-referenced Ranges. (`Cells()`, `Range()`, etc).  It might work, but note that this will refer to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.  I'd add the Worksheet you expect to use those on before the range reference, e.g. `wbkCurBook.Sheets(1).Range("B4") = "Search Criteria"...`.

Comment: Thank for reply, but it is not working